# Splitting a particular column with a simple horizontal line

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to split a particular column with a simple horizontal line .

```
<fo:table>
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell border-color="white" padding-top="5px" padding-bottom="5px"> 
    <fo:block>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=>
    <fo:block border-bottom-width="0.1mm" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="black" font-weight="bold">
```

First I tried to make another table in a column for splitting of data but its not working. `border-bottom` inside `<fo:block >` is also not helping .

The line doesn't seem to properly split the column .How can I do this .

Comment: Is the `fo:table` that you show inside another `fo:table-cell` that you're not showing?  How is what you show not properly splitting the column?

Comment: Actually using table-cell I am achieving that table inside a column which is not properly splitting . Its not merging with the actual column borders

Comment: Screenshot?  Do you have any padding on the enclosing `fo:table-cell`?  Are you specifying a margin for the outer `fo:table`?  It's not clear to me why you don't use a single `fo:block` instead of the inner `fo:table`.  An `fo:table` defaults to automatic table layout and no specified width, so you may just need to use `<fo:table width="100%">` to get the inner table to be the full width of the column.

Comment: I think you may want to rethink your solution. If you truly want to split a single cell horizontally, then you want two rows with the cell in question with content in both and the other cells in that row spanned two rows. That way you would guarantee your borders work, they are on the main table (not something inside a cell you are trying to hack to appear as if it is in the main table).

Comment: I cannot embedd snapshot .For that I need atleast 10 reputation points

Comment: You can upload your snapshot to http://imgur.com/ and add the link to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my comment above, the best solution is change your logic to apply appropriate spanning. Here is some FO to get you thinking:

```
        <fo:table font-size="18pt">
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2" border="1pt solid black" padding="3pt">
                        <fo:block>I am all in one spanned cell</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell  border="1pt solid black"  padding="3pt">
                        <fo:block>I am in top half of the cell</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2"  border="1pt solid black"  padding="3pt">
                        <fo:block>I am all in one spanned cell</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"  padding="3pt">
                        <fo:block>I am in bottom half of the cell</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

The result is:

[image]