# setting up dynamic row height in xsl fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am using below line to achive dynamic row height i.e the height should match with the left column .
But I also need to split the row into different cells ? When I am using simple fo:block-cell attrbutes ,I am not getting dynamic row hight . How can achive both dynamic row hieght and cells ??

```
<fo:table-row display-align="center">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="xalan:distinct(Number)">
                                            <fo:table-cell  block-progression-dimension="auto" >
                                                    <fo:block-container height="10mm">
                                                    <fo:block font-size="9pt" border-right-width="0.1mm"  border-right-style="solid" border-right-color="red" >                                                 
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="">
                                                        <xsl:variable name="">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="">
                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                        <xsl:if test="">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                                                        </xsl:if>
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                    </fo:block-container>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
```

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yqm2.jpg)

Update -

I think one way that it could be done is to insert a vertical line after every cell value .Tried this , but somehow vertical line is not printing .

```
<fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" display-align="center">
           <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="center">
             <fo:table>        
             <fo:table-body>
              <fo:table-row>
              <xsl:for-each select="../../../rateDetails[toGeography/sequence = $currentSequence]">
              <fo:table-cell><!--  block-progression-dimension="auto" border-right-width="0.1mm" border-right-style="solid" border-right-color="black" text-align="center"> -->
               <fo:block-container>
              <fo:block font-size="9pt"><!--  border-right-width="0.1mm" border-right-style="solid" border-right-color="black" text-align="center"> -->
         <xsl:call-template name="currencySymbol">
                  <xsl:with-param name="currencyCode" select="$currencyCode" />
                  </xsl:call-template>
                 <xsl:value-of select="util:formatCurrency(rate,$language,$countryCode)" />
                 </fo:block>
                 </fo:block-container>
                  <fo:block-container reference-orientation="90">
                   <fo:block>
                   <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="100%" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness="0.1mm" color="black"/>
                    </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>

                   </fo:table-cell>
                 </xsl:for-each>
```

Is there anything that I am missing for vertical line insertion .

[snapshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5yrT.jpg)

Comment: Normally, row height is dynamic by default, so you don't need to do anything special. Can you show more of your code so we can see what's preventing that from working?

Comment: @Hobbes- I am also trying ..therefor have provided a layout .hope that will clarify a little

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic'?  Do you have a varying number of `fo:table-cell` in the first column or a varying number of lines of text?  For the first, use `number-rows-spanned` as in my comment to my first answer, and for the second, move the border properties to the `fo:table-cell` as in my second answer.

Comment: If you see the code that I have pasted , i am determining the table cell with a for each loop .If you see the snapshot ,the geography column contains codes .these codes determines the rows-number-spanned .If the codes are more ,the height of the column would increase . These has to be taken into account by the next column as in the figure .

Comment: It seems you have asked a question different that this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629831/splitting-a-particular-column-with-a-simple-horizontal-line. You should mark the answer accepted and clarify the question. If you continue to ask questions and not accept answers, no one is going to answer your questions.

Comment: @KevinBrown.. Sorry ,but I have not received the answer yet . If you see the snapshot you can find what I want to do . I am trying with different method ,that the reason ,you find questions on question .I have updated another possible solution through which I am trying to achieve this . Would appreciate your support

Comment: Your use of an fo:leader to create a vertical line is too complicated. It's much easier to use the cell borders instead, as Tony has shown in his answer.

Comment: @KevinBrown ..Hi ..I am still stuck on this issue ..any suggestions please

Comment: Perhaps the reason you have no answer to your question is the fact that no one understands exactly what your question is. I certainly do not. I do understand your English may not be the best but perhaps if this is such an issue you should take some time to explain what you need to someone that can write it so we can all understand and answer. As it is, I have no idea and most all the answers I see below answer the question as I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the border and padding properties to the `fo:table-cell`, the border will be the full height of the cell:

```
<fo:table-cell border-right="0.1mm solid red">
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `fo:block-container/@height`, you're probably finding that the text in a cell can overflow the 10mm but only the 10mm is being used to determine the row height.  If you remove the `fo:block-container`, you should get a variable-height table row.

Comment: problem I am facing is - In first column - the span row span could be upto 3 rows ,but in the second column it would be 1 row span , but I need that column to be of height equal to first column.

Comment: You've lost me.  If three `fo:table-cell` in the first column have to be the same height as one `fo:table-cell` in the second column, use `number-rows-spanned` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#number-rows-spanned) on the `fo:table-cell` in the second column to make it span the three rows of the `fo:table-cell` in the first column.  Or vice-versa if it's the other way around.  Otherwise, a screenshot of what you currently have and an explanation of why it's wrong would help.

Comment: the values in the first column is dynamic ,so if the values are more the height will increase .

Comment: You've still lost me.  As @Hobbes said, row height is dynamic by default.  Screenshot?

Comment: see if you are able to see the snapshot

Answer (score 0):

The new code sample makes things a bit clearer: you're using 2 nested tables. 
That's another complication you don't need. 
Just use 1 table.
In the first column, place all the geography codes into the first cell. It does not matter how many there are: if you have 1 geography code, the cell will be one line high. If you have 16 geography codes in this cell, the cell will automatically resize to be 3 lines high.

The rest of the row contains cells with the price information. On these cells, define the right border to generate the red vertical line.

```
 <fo:table>    
<fo:table-column column-width="..mm" column-number="1"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="..mm" column-number="2"/>
...you'll have to add some code here to add the correct number of columns to your table...
         <fo:table-body>
          <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell>
          ...place the code to insert the country codes here....
          </fo:table-cell>
          <xsl:for-each select="../../../rateDetails[toGeography/sequence = $currentSequence]">
          <fo:table-cell block-progression-dimension="auto" border-right-width="0.1mm" border-right-style="solid" border-right-color="black" text-align="center">
           <fo:block-container>
          <fo:block font-size="9pt">
     <xsl:call-template name="currencySymbol">
              <xsl:with-param name="currencyCode" select="$currencyCode" />
              </xsl:call-template>
             <xsl:value-of select="util:formatCurrency(rate,$language,$countryCode)" />
             </fo:block>
             </fo:block-container>
               </fo:table-cell>
             </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How the red vertical line will span to all three rows . Also , the first cell geographies are dynamic .Could be 1 , 2 ,3 and so .

Comment: -Please find the snapshot2.This is what I am getting when when adding right border to table cell .

Comment: See my answer, I've edited it again after seeing your second snapshot.

Comment: can you replicate it and check please because when I doing this all the price is getting printed on the same line instead of different cells .

Comment: Hi Hobbes . I am still stuck on this issue :(